# redirect not functioning/alert no display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

cant seem to make this work. i want to go back to the form after submitting. but it just displays

```
**Object not found!**

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

**Error 404**

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.23
```

and also the alert does not pop up.
or it will not pop up because there is an error?

my php

```
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        ?><script>
            alert('Saved Successfully!');
            window.location = ".../cnc/makerForm.php";
        </script><?php
    }
```

my html

```
<div class="w3-border">
    <h6 class = "w3-grey trbl-padding-5 trbl-margin">Maker</h6>
    <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-pale-yellow" onclick="return toggleMakerBox('iframe_makerForm')">+</a>
    <iframe height="400px" width="100%" src="makerForm.php" style="display:none;" name="iframe_makerForm" id="iframe_makerForm"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `...` ? I thought we have only `..` ;)

Answer (score 0):

thanks yall.
i know now of whats wrong with my code.the file in my form is mispelled.

Answer (score -1):

This error means that the file you are targetting does not exist. As pointed out in the comment, it is most probably because you write ... instead .. in the redirect path declaration  `window.location = ".../cnc/makerForm.php";`.

Comment: Try an absolute path something like www://site.com/cnc/makerForm.php

Comment: That means that the file you are referring to does not exist under that path. Can you navigate to the file in URL?

Comment: Ok, go into windows explorer or finder on Mac and navigate to the file manually, is it there?